# $\mathcal{O}(X) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}(Y) \Rightarrow K(X) \cong K(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\mathcal{O}(X) \hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}(Y)$ for irreducible affine varieties $X$ and $Y$. How to show that $K(X) \cong K(Y)$?

Comment: If you take $Y=X\times T$, then the natural projection gives an inclusion $O(X)\subset O(Y)$, but $K(X)$ is not isomorphic to $K(Y)$.